# reading hateaos in a microservice error content has private access in org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel

Tags: spring-hateoas

I'm accepting a HATEAOS response in my spring microservice from my API server.

Everything appears golden, when I debug it, I can see the data.

```
ResponseEntity<CollectionModel<EntityModel<Character>>> m_character = characterProxy.findAll();
```

I created this to get to copy the data:

```
    List<Character> removeHateaos = new ArrayList<>();
    m_character.getBody().getContent().stream().forEach(s -> removeHateaos.add(s.content));
```

I'm getting this error message Error:(39, 93) java: content has private access in org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel

Answer (score 0):

I changed the add to .add(s.getContent()). It is working now.